# Variable that changes itself

Tags: function-construction, recursion

I am trying to store a boolean value into a variable with the additional property that the value changes each time the variable is called.

```
In = var

Out = True

In = var
Out = False
```

My approach was

```
var := If[
    TrueQ[var],
    var = False, 
    var = True
    ]
```

but this is not working. My guess is that is recurring when is calling TrueQ[var]; if this is the case I don't understand why I don't have a recursion limit error.

How can I make my code work?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
flip = True;
var := flip = Not[flip]

var
(*False*)

var
(*True*)

var
(*False*)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way using delayed evaluation and recursive pure function. It allows to only use one variable:

```
ClearAll[var];
var := Function[Null, With[{res = ! #2}, # := #0[#, res]; res], HoldFirst][var, False]
```

So that:

```
var

(* True *)

var

(* False *)

var

(* True *)
```